# JTree cell editor getCellEditorValue() method returning on the wrong object

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtree

I am trying to use a `Renderer` in a `JTree` for a Swing application I am developing, the custom renderer is used only when the tree is a leaf object and is composed of a flow layout. An empty label with an image, a `JComboBox` and finally a label that contains a String.

Initially the `Renderer` is passed a string value via the `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` method in `HazardRenderer.java` it is then set using the `setText()` method in `HazardComboBox.java` the editor then takes the selected renderer instance and sets text using the same `setText()` method.

My initial question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991034/jtree-editor-not-setting-variables), my understanding of the problem has changed though, It would appear that `getCellEditorValue()` in `HazardEditor.java` is returning and altering the `JLabel` that is not my intent, I need it to update the `JComboBox` instead how do I do this? I am attaching the event to the `JComboBox` directly;

```
comboBox.addItemListener(itemListener);
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JTree tree = new JTree();
    tree.setEditable(true);
    tree.setRootVisible(false);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new HazardRenderer());
    tree.setCellEditor(new HazardEditor());
    //tree.setModel() excluded for brevity
    return new JScrollPane(tree);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new Main().makeUI());
      f.pack();
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

HazardComboBox.java

```
public class HazardComboBox extends JPanel {
    private JLabel lblLabel = new JLabel("Placeholder");
    private JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(HazardSelection.values());

    public HazardComboBox() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(HazardComboBox.class.getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/file.gif")));
        add(label);

        comboBox.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 5));
        comboBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(comboBox);

        lblLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        add(lblLabel);
    }

    public JComboBox getComboBox() {
        return comboBox;
    }

    public JLabel getLabel() {
        return lblLabel;
    }

    public void setText(String name) {
        getLabel().setText(name);
    }

}
```

HazardRenderer.java

```
public class HazardRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    private HazardComboBox leafRenderer = new HazardComboBox();
    private DefaultTreeCellRenderer nonLeafRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object hazard, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf,
            int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (leaf) {
            leafRenderer.setText(hazard.toString());
            return leafRenderer;
        }
        return nonLeafRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, hazard, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
    }

}
```

HazardEditor.java

```
    public class HazardEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

    private HazardRenderer renderer = new HazardRenderer();
    private HazardComboBox component;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode;
    //private ServerInfo info;
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private String val;

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {

        val = value.toString();
        component = (HazardComboBox)renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, isSelected, expanded, leaf, row, true);

        if(leaf) {

            treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;

            //info = (ServerInfo)treeNode.getUserObject();

            comboBox = component.getComboBox();

            ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                    comboBox.removeItemListener(this);
                    fireEditingStopped();
                }
            };

            comboBox.addItemListener(itemListener);

        }
        return component;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        //info.setChecked(comboBox.isSelected());
        //return info;      
        //System.out.println(component.getComboBox().getSelectedIndex());
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {

        if(!(event instanceof MouseEvent)) return false;

        MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent)event;
        JTree tree = (JTree)event.getSource();

        TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());

        if(path == null) return false;

        Object lastComponent = path.getLastPathComponent();

        if(lastComponent == null) return false;

        DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)lastComponent;

        return treeNode.isLeaf();
    }

}
```

HazardSelection.java

```
public enum HazardSelection {
    NOTCONSIDERED("Not Considered"), NOTAPPLICABLE("Not Applicable"), CONSIDERED("Considered"), HAZARD("Hazard");

    private String name;

    private HazardSelection (String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm miss there stop cell editor, missing there fireXxxUpdated (never used AbstractCellEditor for JTree  == quite hate this ...), AbstractWhatever required to override all events (storing value from editor to model, the same as for JTable) that are implemented in DefaultWhatever by default,

Comment: very good question, structured, with SSCCE / MCVE, for me question of this month

Comment: @mKorbel Thank you, could you explain the problem again? I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: value from editor must be saved into model, otherwise (after XxxEditor gone away) value stay unchanged (XxxRenderer painting value from model)

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CheckBoxNodeTreeSample) is AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor with ItemListener, is ... different